# Making SVG 'symbol' Accessible

Tags: svg, accessibility

I am looking for clarification about combining `<title>` and `<desc>` with the  element for **Accessibility**. Is the following a valid implemention?

```
<svg>
  <title>This is an SVG</title>
  <desc">Lorem ipsum descriptum...</desc>
  <use xlink:href="#symbolID"></use>
</svg>
```

Or would you place it in the `<symbol>` element like this?

```
<symbol id="symbolID">
  <title>This is an svg</title>
  <desc>Lorem ipsum ...</desc>
  <path d="......"/>
</symbol>
```

Would screen readers be able to pick these up?

Comment: I'm doubtful that the accessibilty features are 'readable' from inside a `<use>/<symbol>` so teh first option would seem more likely to be read.

Comment: Some interesting reading - https://gist.github.com/davidhund/564331193e1085208d7e

Comment: How are you calling it? Does it have a role? If you have a URL I can test it in a screen reader and tell you how it behaves.

Comment: @aardrian here's a pen if you would like to test it out. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEqaKV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `role="img"` and a screen reader can pick it up. It may announce both the `<title>` and the `<desc>` depending on screen reader, browser, and versions of each.

For a little extra compatibility you can added `aria-labelledby` to tell the screen reader where to look for the explicit accessible name (which also means it may not announce the `<desc>`). Some combos may read the `<title>` twice as a result, too, so it behooves you to be brief.

```
<a href="#"> foo
  <svg role="img" aria-labelledby="twitterTitle">
    <title id="twitterTitle">Twitter Account</title>
    <desc>Twitter account for example</desc>
    <use xlink:href="#twitter"/>
  </svg>
</a>
```

[I forked your CodePen and marked it up](http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/dXkLoa?editors=1000).

You may have already seen these two articles, but if not:

- [Tips for Creating Accessible SVG](https://www.sitepoint.com/tips-accessible-svg/) at SitePoint by Léonie Watson,
- [Accessible SVGs](https://css-tricks.com/accessible-svgs/) at CSS-Tricks by Heather Migliorisi.